# apache freemarker - render a list as a table

Tags: list, freemarker

Good morning everyone,

I was wondering if someone can help me to get this done? I'm trying to render an ArrayList as a table using Apache Freemarker.

Imagine the following code (java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// freemarker
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_28);
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("./src/"));
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
;
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");

Map m = Collections.singletonMap("names", Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux",
"corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred",
"plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"
));

//
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
temp.process(m, out);
}
```

With this template:

```
<Start>
<#list 0..names?size-1 as i>
${names[i]}
</#list>
<end>
```

It Will be outputed like this:

```
<Start>
foo
bar
baz
qux
quux
corge
grault
garply
waldo
fred
plugh
xyzzy
thud
<end>
```

I was wondering if it was possible with freemarker to have it in columns:

```
<Start>
foo        bar         baz
qux        quux        corge
grault     garply      waldo
fred       plugh       xyzzy
thud
<end>
```

Any idea? Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: This is how a simple listing goes (no need to iterate through indexes and such):
`<#list names as name> ${name} </#list>`

Answer (score 0):

`?chunk` can slice up a sequence to smaller sequences (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_chunk), so with the example of a HTML table you could do this:

```
<table>
  <#list names?chunk(3) as row>
    <tr>
      <#list row as name><td>${name}</td></#list>
    </tr>
  </#list>
</table>
```